# prove the equivalence of sequential and open set def of lower hemicontinuity of correspondence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

I want to know how to prove the equivalence of the two definitions of lower hemi continuity of correspondences. I know how to derive the upper hemi continuity equivalence, but struggling with the lower counterpart.

**Def.** $\Phi\colon X\to\to Y$ is lower hemi-continuous (lhc) at $x\in X$ if for every open $V\subset Y$ with $\Phi(x)\cap V\neq \emptyset$ there exists open $U\subset X$ s.t. $x'\in U$ such that $\Phi(x')\cap V\neq\emptyset$.

**Claim** $\Phi\colon X\to\to Y$ is lhc at $x\in X$ iff for every $y\in\Phi(x)$ and $(x_n)\to x$ there exists $(y_n)\to y$ with $y_n\in\Phi(x_n)$.

Comment: Please do not post an image, as essentially asking your question for you.  And I see not context added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this notion under the name *lower semicontinuity*.

**Fact** Let $X,Y$ be two metric spaces, $\Phi\colon X\to 2^Y\setminus\{\emptyset\} $ be a multivalued mapping and let $x\in X$ The following two conditions are equivallent:

1. for any open subset $V\subset Y$ such that $\Phi(x)\cap V\neq\emptyset$ there exists an open subset $U\subset X$ such that $\Phi(x')\cap V\neq\emptyset$ for all $x'\in U$;
2. for any $y\in\Phi(x)$ and any $x_n\to x$ we have $\mathrm{dist}(y,\Phi(x_n))\to 0$
3. for any $y\in\Phi(x)$ and any $x_n\to x$ there exists $y_n\in \Phi(x_n)$ such that $y_n\to y$.

**Proof**

- $[1.\implies 2.]$: Take $y$ and $(x_n)$ as in 2. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. From 1. used for $V=B(y,\varepsilon)$ we get $\delta>0$ such that $\Phi(x')\cap V\neq \emptyset$ for any $x'\in U:=B(x,\delta)$. Therefore, since $x_n\to x$, for almost all $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $\Phi(x_n)\cap B(y,\varepsilon)\neq\emptyset$, which implies $\mathrm{dist}(y,\Phi(x_n))<\varepsilon$.
- $[2.\implies 3.]$: Take $y$ and $(x_n)$ as in 2. Take any $y_n\in\Phi(x_n)$ such that $$d(y,y_n)<\mathrm{dist}(y,\Phi(x_n))+\frac 1n.$$ This is possible from the very definition of the distance function. The choice of $y_n$ gives $d(y,y_n)\to 0+0=0$.
- $[3.\implies 1.]$: Assume 3. and on the contrary assume that 1. is not satisfied. Then there exists an open subset $V\subset Y$ such that $\Phi(x)\cap V\neq\emptyset$ but for all $n>0$ there exists $x_n\in B(x,1/n)$ such that $\Phi(x_n)\cap V=\emptyset$. Take any $y\in \Phi(x)\cap V$ (this set is nonempty). Evidently $x_n\to x$. From 3. we obtain $y_n\in\Phi(x_n)$ such that $y_n\to y$, so $y_n\in V$ for almost all $n$. Therefore for sufficiently large $n$ we have $y_n\in \Phi(x_n)\cap V=\emptyset$, a contradiction.